# handlebars.js is not recognised by ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, gruntjs

I try to update https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences

with the newest versions of some scripts. All work except `Ember (1.2.0)` gives an error:

```
    Assertion failed: Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars version 1.0 or 1.1. Include a SCRIPT tag in the HTML HEAD linking to the Handlebars file before you link to Ember.
```

Error disappears when I activate the same script without dependencies but with

```
      <script src="../dependencies/handlebars.js"></script>
```

Comment: This - https://github.com/gcollazo/brunch-with-ember-reloaded/tree/coffeescript skeleton has already updated to latest versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think question should be marked as answered. I got it work with https://github.com/gcollazo/brunch-with-ember-reloaded